# C# - Get file path from connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, connection-string

Is there an existing method in C# to extract the file path from a string that represents a `ConnectionString` to a `SqlCE` *.sdf* file? I want to check if the file exists at initialization and back it up if the file has been modified.

Sample connection string:

```
strConn = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dbAlias.sdf";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit late perhaps, but I came across this question wile struggling with the same problem. You can find the location of the `|DataDirectory|` folder with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")`. So your connectionstring can be translated like this:

```
strConn .Replace("|DataDirectory|", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString())
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class to parse existing Sql Compact connection string.

Comment: It would be nice to explain to him what property contains the DataDirectory he is looking for.

Comment: SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.DataSource gives "|DataDirectory|\\dbPerson.sdf" again, not physical path.

Comment: @Nix:  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",path);

Comment: For LocalDB, use: new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(str).AttachDBFilename.Replace("|DataDirectory|", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString())

Answer (score 4):

You could just create the connection and get the data source from it as a property:

```
string data;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    data = conn.DataSource;
}
```

Comment: +1 because you give him the property that defines the directory.

Comment: I still need to find |DataDirectory| alias. Currently I know it but how about other aliases -if any- Absolute path would be nice....

Comment: Is there any other alias like |DataDirectory| ?

Comment: Does not work with LocalDB connectionstrings, it just returns "(LocalDB)\v11.0" on the DataSource property.

Answer (score 0):

For LocalDB and SqlConnection (not CE):

```
public static string GetFilePathFromConnectionString(string connectionString)
{
    var attachDbFileName = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString).AttachDBFilename;
    return attachDbFileName.Replace("|DataDirectory|", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString());
}
```