# winforms DataDirectory location

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce, datadirectory

I have a c# winforms app that uses SQL compact and here is the connection string for the DB:

```
<add name="Test.Properties.Settings.TestManagerConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\TestManager.sdf"
            providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
```

How can I get the path that the connection string is pointing to? ie: C:\Users\name\AppData... etc

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941943/c-sharp-get-file-path-from-connection-string

Comment: Thanks but the problem I am still facing is that `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")` always comes back with `null`

Comment: Also how can I change the |DataDirectory| in the connstring above to something like `connectionString="Data Source=\Database\TestManager.sdf"` so that when the app is starting it is not looking for the DB in the |DataDirectory|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to move it to a different directory? By default a non-administrative user does not have access to make changes in the Program Files directory tree. AppData is a user specific store that (in the case of network hosted profiles) points to the appropriate directory on the network for the user's app data directory.

If you want to share data for multiple users, there is the All_Users Data Directory. I'm not sure how to specify it with the SqlCE connection string though.

**Update**

[Here is the answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/) to determining the appdata directory.

> To set the DataDirectory property, call the AppDomain.SetData method.
>   If you do not set the DataDirectory property, the following default
>   rules will be applied to access the database folder:
>
> 1. For applications that are put in a folder on the user's computer,
>      the database folder uses the application folder.
> 2. For applications that are running under ClickOnce, the database folder uses the
>      specific data folder that is created.

Comment: I do not want to move it, I actually need the full path to it. C:\Users\... etc

Comment: Ah I understand now. I thought your question was asking originally how to change the directory to be under program files.